# Search multiple SDF files

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-ce

I have a process that backs up my remove SQL Server database to local SDF (SQL CE) database files daily.

What I need is an easy way to search across multiple SDF files.  For example, suppose I want to find all occurrences of a name within all of the backups.  Instead of opening each individual SDF file -- one by one -- with Enterprise Manager, I'd like to be able to do a search across all the files and show the results in one centralized place.  Maybe like a plug-in for Windows Search, etc.

If you're familiar with Notepad++, think about how it's File Search feature works.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or am I just dreaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to accomplish this, unless yo write your own search filter for SQL Server Compact. But you could use a tool like my SQL Server Command command line utility  http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com  together with some clever batch/Powershell code to query across multiple sdf file and collect the results in a singel file.

Comment: Thanks! You could also use my ExportSqlCe tool to dump entire database files as a text files, if you prefer to search text files rather than tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script or program that opens/connects to a set of .SDFs (all files in a folder, from a hardcoded list, from a table in a specialized/master ..SDF), execute a (list of) statement(s) like `SELECT ... FROM table WHERE field = 'needle'`, and display the resultsets to the console, a .HTML file, or push them to still another .SDF.